# Getting zero answer while using DO-WHILE loop

Tags: c, do-while

I tried to calculate the tot(total fee) in the do-while loop, but all I get is tot=0.00?! Why is this happening? And after that I get a message: it said the variable fee is not being initialised?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int cofno;
    float tot=0.0;
    float fee;
    char option;
    do{

        printf("Enter cofno: ");
        scanf("%d",&cofno);
        if(cofno>0)
        {
            printf("Key in (h/c): ");
            scanf("%c",&option);
            getchar();
            switch(option)
            {case 'h':fee=cofno*1.80;
            break;
            case 'c': fee=cofno*2.50;
                break;
            }

            tot=tot+fee;
            //the program will repeat until the user key in negative value or zero
        }
    }while(cofno>0);

    printf("\ntot=RM%.2f \n\n",tot);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The `getchar()` should be before the `scanf("%c",&option);`

Comment: ah sorry i forgot about that part. Thank you @Ring Ø sir. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf(" %c",&option);` This will solve the problem for you. The reason the `' '` is provided in the `scanf` so that it can consume the white space characters.

What happened earlier was that your character input got the `\n` from previous input.

To check the thing that it inputted `\n` try outputting the option like this
`printf("[%c]",option);` you will see output

```
[
]
```

Also the `break` statement you provide is breaking for the case staement. Not the while loop. You have infinite loop now. You can solve this with a added condition.

```
...
tot=tot+fee;
if(option == 'c' || option =='h')
    break;
...
```

Even more simply, you could have changed the `while` condition overall and make it like this

```
while(cofno<=0);
```

this conforms to your idea *the program will repeat until the user key in negative value or zero* more suitably.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @coderredoc . You just save my life man. Thank you.